# Trouble Proxying All Requests From ASP.NET Core to a local Node Server

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, asp-net-core-spa-services

I've got my ASP.NET Core 3 server template project working correctly so that I an browse to it at https://localhost:5000 .  I also have, on my same localhost running on port 4000 a node server that is working correctly when I browser to it at https://localhost:4000.

What I want is for all requests that come in to https://localhost:5000/nodejs to go to https://localhost:4000/.  that is for example, I want

https://localhost:5000/api/Images/peter.png

to return what would normally be served from https://localhost:4000/Images/peter.png

(and of course, all other requests should be mapped similarly.  All urls, not just the one I mention above).

I tried using the nuget package AspNetCore.Proxy and when I use it as below, it only proxies the root and not any other URL.

What is the simplest way to get all URL proxied from my asp.net core project to my node server?

`ApiController.js`

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using AspNetCore.Proxy;
namespace reactapp.Controllers
{
    public class NextJsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("nodejs")]
        public Task OpenNextJs()
        {
            return this.ProxyAsync($"http://localhost:4000");
        }
    }
}
```

and in `startup.js`

```
services.AddProxies();
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is for all requests that come in to https://localhost:5000/nodejs to go to https://localhost:4000/.

You can proxy the request as below:

```cs
app.Map("/nodejs", builder => {  
    // now that the raw req path `/nodejs/...rest` has been change to `/...rest`
    //     proxy to the following server
    builder.RunProxy("http://localhost:4000");
});
```